# Efficient process is NSXML or TouchXML

Tags: iphone, touchxml, nsxml

I am parsing a simple XML file, which one i can use for efficient parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a blog which compares all parser methods according to their efficiency, you ca find it [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project).

Answer (score 1):

**The blog writer has compared all the XML parser available for iOS.**

you will get the answer of the follwing questions.

**1 > XML Parser Performance Comparison App**

**2 > Which To Choose?**

**3 > Where To Go From Here?**

Check the below blog post

[How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)